# How to keep Excel column width format when convert data to text using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, text, format

I need to paste my Excel to text without changing the Excel format. I already made the VBA to copy my data. But I do not how to paste them without ignoring the Excel format.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. (1) Please show the code you already have. (2) Can you show with an example what you exactly mean by not changing the format? Showing a screenshot would help a lot.

Comment: I cant show the code because I dont have it. I'm a complete beginner I dont even know how to start it. Its my school project. What I meant is that when i copy the table in excel then pasted it on text file, the words that are separated by column became "tab". I wanted it to become "" .(nothing)

Comment: Then do a replace `tab` into nothing within the text editor after you pasted in the text file. That would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like below:

```
copyRange.Copy    'copyRange is range you want to copy
With Range(cell_ref) 'cell_ref should is first cell of paste area e.g. Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```